# Manually setting chapter counter overrides TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters

I have parts for each year:

```
\part{2011}
...
\part{2012}
...
etc.
...
```

I want the chapter number to be the month of that year for stylistic purposes (e.g. like how the chapter number is shown [here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/Examples/classicthesis-book-xelatex.pdf))

```
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{August 2011}
```

But now in the `ToC` the link for the "August 2011" chapter points to the page for "August 2010". How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you compile the main file twice?

Comment: Can you please provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: I guess the problem is the resetting of the chapter number from (12) to 1 for the next part (corresponding to a new year) this confuses `hyperref` -- however, the resetting is not done by default!

Comment: I guess one could append the year to the hyperref-label making it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resetting of the chapter counter after a new part (= year) confuses the hyperlink settings from `hyperref` in some cases unless the option `hypertexnames=false` is used.

This 'solution' uses an automatic setup of month names in loop, but it's not suited of course in this form for a productive run with content between the month chapters

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{assoccnt}%
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{%
  hypertexnames=false
}%

\newcounter{monthloopcounter}
\newcounter{yearcounter}
\setcounter{yearcounter}{2009}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{part}{yearcounter}



\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatletter



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{\theyearcounter}

\forloop{monthloopcounter}{1}{\value{monthloopcounter} < 13}{%
  \chapter{\monthname[\number\value{monthloopcounter}] \theyearcounter}%
}%


\part{\theyearcounter}

\forloop{monthloopcounter}{1}{\value{monthloopcounter} < 13}{%
  \chapter{\monthname[\number\value{monthloopcounter}] \theyearcounter}%
}%


\part{\theyearcounter}

\forloop{monthloopcounter}{1}{\value{monthloopcounter} < 13}{%
  \chapter{\monthname[\number\value{monthloopcounter}] \theyearcounter}%
}%

\end{document}
```

I used `assoccnt` package to add a co-marching counter which is updated each time a new `\part` is used.

[image]

Comment: `hypertexnames=false` works fine, thank you!